# Sync or link Excel Spreadsheet with Outlook Calendar

Tags: excel, outlook

Good morning,

I would like to sync my Excel Spreadsheet with Outlook calendar.

This spreadsheet is to be updated every 5-10 mins. Is it possible to set some periodic updates or shall I do everything manually?

I found a lot examples in the web, showing how to export Excel data to Outlook, but there are only single operations, that must be repeated.

One reasonable option is provided here:
https://classroom.synonym.com/sync-yahoo-calendar-android-device-8556.html
but is pretty much other way round what I am looking for, because it's embedding calendar to the Excel. 
I would like to link Excel Sporeadsheet with Outlook calendar.

Is there a some way to do this i.e via VBA, PHP, SQL etc?

Answer (score 0):

Usually programming such an action can be done in two ways: Polling or event driven.

Polling means using a timer to do your work repeatingly every period of time. Search for 'VBA' and 'timer'.

Event driven means you will take a subscription on an event. The other side will raise an event when something has changed. Like a subscription on a newspaper: the newspaperboy delivers a newspaper when something happened in the world. When you hear or see the newspaperboy, you walk to the mailbox and empty it.

Usually event driven is the most beautiful solution, because it doesn't use a lot of CPU (with the newspaper example, you can sit back and relax until a newspaper is delivered). But when you are polling, you will have to check the mailbox (calendar) every time.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) is a Items.ItemChange event about when an item has changed. I hope it fits your needs. If you want to understand better how it works, search for "event handling".

If the link is broken, here is the example from that page:

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 

    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 

End Sub 



Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object) 

Dim prompt As String 

    If VBA.Format(Item.Start, "h") >= "17" And Item.Sensitivity <> olPrivate Then 

        prompt = "Appointment occurs after hours. Mark it private?" 

        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 

            Item.Sensitivity = olPrivate 

            Item.Display 

        End If 

    End If 

End Sub
```